# Regarding serialization of including the members which cannot be serialized

Tags: java, serialization

I was going through the process of serialization and what I have analysed is that the memebers that can not be serialized are transisent and static , Please advise is there any other functionality also that can not be serialized other than these two..? please advise.

Guys Please advise..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I have analysed is that the memebers that can not be serialized are transisent and static ,

The are not serialized by default.  That does mean they cannot be Serialized with custom serialization.  Note: there are many classes in the JDK which have transient fields which are serialized a custom way.

> Please advise is there any other functionality also that can not be serialized other than these two..?

You cannot serialize objects which do not implement Serializable and are non-`transient` and non-`static`.

Note: you can use custom serialization to serialize any object provided its `transient`.

Comment: Thanks a lot fantastic Man..! As you hava written ..we can use  custom serialization to serialize any object provided its transient..could you please update in your post an examplpe that will be a great to understand..!!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I remember is, that you can only serialize members which implement Serializable on there own.

Further information:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html

Comment: I think I missread your question. You asked about functionality that can not be serialized and not about general serialization conditions. I'm not sure about other functionality that can not be serialized, sorry.